# Are Strongly typed ArrayLists the better choice in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

When I program in C# , there are times when I need a strongly typed collection:

I often create a class that inherits from the `ArrayList`:

```
using System.Collections;
public class Emails: ArrayList
{
  public new Email this[int i]
  {
     get
     {
        return (Email)base[i];
     }
     set
     {
        base[i] = value;
     }
  }
}
```

I realize this is probably not the correct way to inherit from a collection. If I want to inherit from a strongly typed collection in C#, how should I do it, and what class should I choose to inherit from?

Comment: In general I try to avoid implementation inheritance most of the time, except when other methods are significantly more awkward.  It's too easy to trip over.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you want is a *generic*, like `List<T>`.

```
public class Emails : List<Email>
{
}
```

This has all of the methods of ArrayList and then some, and you get type safety without having to do any extra work.

Note, however, that inheriting from `List<T>` can sometimes cause you more trouble than it's worth. A better idea is to implement `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`, and use the `List<T>` internally to implement the interface.

Comment: Thanks to every one here for answering so quickly. I'll change my bad habit right away!

Comment: Love this method. ;) I use it a LOT when I'm coding and need a group of objects with quick indexers.

Comment: Don't inherit from List<T>.  Just use it.  If you really want a new type, create an alias.

Comment: -1 Not the right answer. Deriving from List<T> is frought with problems. +1 to Joel Coehoorn.

Comment: @Joel - wouldn't the alias have to be repeated in every file?

Comment: Do NOT use alias. :) It's terrible in C#.

Answer (score 9):

Forget both ArrayList and List. The "right" thing to do would be to derive from Collection and call your class something that ends in Collection.

```
public sealed class EmailCollection : Collection<Email>
{

}
```

Comment: @Josh- I got your point. I agree about the syntax you use (emailCollection) make more sense and you know exactly at what you referring to! But what make you choose among all the different possibilities the dotnet framework is offering:  the collection.
[using System.Collections.ObjectModel;]
This has mostly the same methods than the List or the ArrayList
Is that something performance wise, or just a matter of taste and habit ?

Comment: Well, Collection(T) is designed to be used as a base class. So if you were going to derive your own class to expose in an object model, that would be the one I'd use. If are not exposing it, then I'd use List but wouldn't derive from it - I'd just create a List(Email). As for naming it, it's just a convention FooCollection for example as opposed to Foos.

Comment: Using Collection(T) or IEnumerable(T) is a good habit to get into for modeling your domain.

Other thing to think about: When you expose this collection to callers will they be modifying it? Will it be common for them to want to access elements by index? Will they need to know the number of elements in the collection?

Very often a Collection(T) will suffice, and then you haven't exposed functionality that is not meaningful. If your collection goes over the wire, for example, e.g. WCF, does it make sense for it to have an Add() method? Shouldn't Add() happen over your service layer instead?

Answer (score 5):

If you're not stuck with .Net 1.1, you really should forget about `ArrayList` and use the generic `List<T>` instead. You get strong typing and better performances to boot.

Answer (score 3):

In general `new` should be avoided for member declaration if at all possible.

As of C# 2 though you can use generics. `List<email> list = new List<email>();`

Answer (score 2):

Not really, that's what generics are for.

Answer (score 1):

Generics seem much more appropriate. For example,

```
List<email>
```

in this case. Why reinvent the wheel and perform worse?

Answer (score 0):

If you use .net 2.0 or + i would go with a generic collection